# Set static data/state on React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking to set references to a `new ResizeObserver` and a DOM element in my `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.  I need these references to be accessible in `componentWillUnmount`, so currently I am setting them on the React component itself (via `this`).

However, this is problematic with Typescript, as Typescript does not recognize the properties `ro` and `el` on my React component.  Furthermore, I am not even sure if this is the best way to go about doing this.  Is this a good convention or are there better ways to set static data?

```
public componentWillUnmount() {
    this.ro.unobserve(this.el);
}

public componentDidMount() {
    this.el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.el);
    this.ro = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
        for (let entry of entries) {
            // set state
        }
    });

    this.ro.observe(this.el);
}
```

Comment: You can also try storing `ro` in state. `el` should always exist as `this.el` if you use the ref callback syntax: `<button ref={ref => this.el = ref} />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this typed by declaring the `ro` and `el` as optional properties in your component's class. Just add

```
private ro? : ResizeObserver
private el? : Element
```

They are optional as they are not set in the constructor, so you'll have to add a (superfluous) existence check to each place where you use them. E.g.:

```
if (this.ro && this.el) {
  this.ro.unobserve(this.el);
}
```

Both will always exist in `componentWillUnmount` because they're initialized in `componentDidMount`, but that's not something you can express in TypeScript.